# How to run sqlite3 in android phone

Tags: android, sqlite

I push sqlite3 in /system/xbin and run sqlite3 then get a error 'permission denied'.
The file permission is '-rw-rw-rw-'. I try to change permission to 777, when run sqlite3 i get a error 'syntax error:"<" unexpected'.

Comment: Post the commands log, difficult to see what you tried otherwise.